# MergExt Datagrid Scroller

Tags: livecode

Is there anyway I can use the MergExt Datagrid Scroller without Drop Tools. I am unable to get Drop Tools as they don't yet have a version that works with Livecode Community. If anybody could give me any help it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. Like this:

- Set the mainstack of the mergDataGridScroller stack to the mainstack of your app
- Create a DataGrid
- Create a group that wraps the datagrid and set it's margins to 0
- set the behavior of the wrapper group to the long id of btn "mergDataGridScroller Behavior" of stack "mergDataGridScroller"

You should be good to go now.

I know Ken is working on DropTools for LC Community but I also know he's a busy guy ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help Monte. I can't seem to set the mainstack of mergDataGridScroller to the main stack of my app though. Everytime I select my App from the Dropdown menu in the Property Inspector it always sets itself back to it's own mainstack. Any ideas?

Comment: Ah... because it's got a substack you need to delete that first

Comment: Hi Monte. Is this scroller using a method of expanding the data grid to its full size and the wrapper (a field) of equal size, grouping both and scrolling the wrapper? Also let me know if  MergExt Datagrid Scroller can be used on its own, without purchasing all the other MergExt modules that you have on your website, and with LC Community version. Also do you think that using it with a data grid with 600-1000 records will be snappy, quick and responsive? Have you tested it with so many records on an older, slower android device?

Comment: Yes that's the only way to get smooth scrolling of groups in LiveCode at the moment. It doesn't have a GPL compatible license so unless it's for personal use then don't use it with Community. There are limits to group size to consider when getting up into the thousands of records. You will likely notice some loading time. It's optimised for smooth scrolling.